# How to use IIS to manage RESTful web application developed with C++ REST SDK

Tags: c++, rest, iis, cpprest-sdk

I have developed a RESTful web application using the C++ REST SDK that, at the moment is a command line application that is run on startup.

I'm wondering if it's possible for this command line application to be managed as an IIS Website instead of just a plain command line app? And if so, how do I go about doing this?

Comment: Let your command line server monitor at `http://localhost:5000` and then set up IIS as a reverse proxy for it, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/reverse-proxy-with-url-rewrite-v2-and-application-request-routing

Comment: Thanks @LexLi but, this doesn't allow IIS to manage to application. I.E, If I restart the website in IIS, it won't restart the command line app.

Comment: That’s exactly what a reverse proxy does (nginx and others work the same way). The server side support in C++ REST SDK is still in beta, and you might wait and see if they will introduce better IIS integration.

Comment: There is currently no perfect solution to host this website application in IIS. IIS working as a reverse proxy is an option worth considering. 
Since this project has been very old since 2017, I recommend that you use asp.net core Webapi to create and use Rest API.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio